# Reputation increase not visible.

Tags: bug, stackexchange

I have accounts on different sites of stackexchange. But on my math.stackexchange account instead of its reputation and comments. Reputation and comments of stackoverflow are visible. How to stop this? So that I can see reputation of math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

The inbox and the achievements in the top-bar are network-wide by design. That is, notifications of all your accounts are aggregated into one stream.

If you want information specific to one site you can find it, for the most common types of events at least, on your profile page:

- [Reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation)
- [Comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses)

Comment: My stackoverflow comments and reputation are old and math.stackexchange comments and reputation increase are new but they are not visible.

Comment: So you do not receive a notification about this comment? Also are you talking about this account or some other account?

Comment: Some other account

Comment: Any reason why you do not ask it with that other account then? It could simplify things. Another thing to consider is that if at some point you lost reputation, for some time, you would only be inform about increase beyond your earlier top score, not steps towards it. So if you loose 25 due to a delete, say, and then get a +10 you will get it, but you will not receive a notification for it.